# FB Comments - not logged in

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I am trying to switch from Disqus to Facebook comments, but I have issues with the comment widget.

Here is the page: http://www.czechgamer.com/hledani.php?tag=z-domova#4

The issue is that even though I am logged in to Facebook, the comment box on the page doesn't show me as logged in. I have "Log In to Post" there button but in fact, can't do anything other than to click on the default avatar picture, which opens new window - a facebook page - where I am logged in. But on my page, whatever I try, I am still not logged in...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: Sorry Robert, but in my browser every thing is just properly showed. Can you supply the screenshot of your error?